# iOS7: Not able to add search bar to Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

In my `SearchViewController.m`, I added

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];


    self.searchResultsView.dataSource = self;
    self.searchResultsView.delegate = self;

    NSLog(@"fetching businesses");
    [self fetchBusinesses];

    // fix UITableViewCell height
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 90;
}
```

But I can not see search bar. All I see is
[image]

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add search bar programatically like follows:

make property of both **UISearchBar** and **UISearchDisplayController** i.e.

> ```
> @property (nonatomic,strong) UISearchBar *searchBar ;
> @property (nonatomic,strong) UISearchDisplayController *searchDisplayController;
> ```

**then write following code:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
     searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
        searchBar.delegate =self;
        self.searchBar.showsCancelButton =TRUE;
        [self.searchBar setHidden:NO];
        [self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
        [self.searchDisplayController setActive:YES];

        [self.view addSubview:self.searchBar];

        self.searchDisplayController =[[UISearchDisplayController alloc]initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self];
        self.searchDisplayController.delegate =self;
        self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource= self;
        self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;

}
```

also you need to implements **UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate**  delegates for the same ViewController

Hope This code will work for you . Give it a try and let me know your feedback.

Comment: he is asking about What am I missing, Not how to implement UISearchBar, displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar Method working only in ios 7 and with this we can set the search bar Under navigation bar without write too much code

Comment: hey , it works for ios 6 too. and it is working perfectly awesome for me. And about missing stuff, he might have done some silly mistake and i would love to help him by giving the step by step solution instead of giving silly commnents

Comment: check apple developer documentation, you have to find the answer there https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISearchDisplayController/displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar

Comment: Though it is started on ios 7. It works fine for ios 6, 6.1 or in ios 5 too. The thing is that we need to tackle the problem of @daydreamer which he is facing . i think whatever the code he has written is having the missing stuff and It has covered in code snippet which i have pasted.

Answer (score 0):

Now i find the answer , i just tested it on my side and its working fine at my end ,

```
 // init search bar
    UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    searchBar.delegate = self;
    searchBar.showsCancelButton=YES;

    // set up searchDisplayController
    UISearchDisplayController *searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc]
                                                   initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
    searchController.delegate = self;


    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```